# how scaling svg img from xml string

Tags: html, angular, svg

I am getting a svg file from the user as a string. I need to be able to resize it. I just came up with this way

```
const rew = / width="[^"]+"/;
const reh = / height="[^"]+"/;
svgStr = svgStr.replace(rew, ` width="${width}"`);
svgStr = svgStr.replace(reh, ` height="${height}"`);
```

But this is clearly not how you want to work with svg. This does not work for all versions, and besides, this approach changes the size, but keeps the proportion of the image, and I need to be able to stretch / compress it. How to do it right?

Comment: You can add class and use widht and height to change the sizes, and transform:scaleX if you want to not keep the proportions

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`preserveAspectRatio` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) to keep the aspect ratio of your SVG.

For the size, I would ask for the width / height, then put it in a container like this

```html
<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{ width: width, height: height }">
  <!-- SVG width = 100%, SVG height = 100% !-->
  {{ svgString | sanitize }}
</div>
```